# Concatenate XSLT element values based on another element value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have the following XML:

```
<root>
    <attributes>
        <attribute_value>ID1</attribute_value>
        <attribute_name>id</attribute_name>
    </attributes>
    <attributes>
        <attribute_value>ID2</attribute_value>
        <attribute_name>id</attribute_name>
    </attributes>
    <attributes>
        <attribute_value>some-link</attribute_value>
        <attribute_name>link</attribute_name>
    </attributes>
</root>
```

I want to iterate over the file and concatenate all the "attribute_value" values based on the "attribute_name" value using XSLT (1.0 or 2.0). So in this case the output would be:

```
<root>
    <element name="id" value="ID1"/>
    <element name="ids" value="ID1,ID2"/>
    <element name="link" value="some-link"/>
</root>
```

The "id" element should contain the first value encountered and the "ids" element would contain the concatenated value. How can this be achieved? I have a working XSLT where I use the  tag and iterate over all the attributes, but not able to get around this problem.

The following is my current XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="root">
            <root>
                <xsl:for-each select="attributes">  
                    <xsl:variable name="attribute_name" select="attribute_name"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="attribute_value" select="attribute_value"/>
                    <xsl:if test="$attribute_name = 'link'">
                        <element name="link">
                            <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="$attribute_value" /></xsl:attribute>
                        </element>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </root>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you show the XSLT you currently have? Thank you!

Comment: There are only two distinct `attribute_name` values in your input; why do you have three `element` nodes in the output?

Comment: @TimC: Added the XSLT.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: As explained, I need two elements, "id" for first id encountered and "ids" which will contain concatenated values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using XSLT 2.0, you can use `xsl:for-each-group` here

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="attributes" group-by="attribute_name">
```

Then to output the first element, you can do this:

```
 <element name="{attribute_name}" value="{attribute_value}" />
```

(Note the use of [attribute value templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) to simplify creating the attributes)

Then if there are more than one element in the group, you could create the concatenated version like so:

```
<element name="{@attribute_name}s" value="{string-join(current-group()/attribute_value, ',')}" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="attributes" group-by="attribute_name">  
                <element name="{attribute_name}" value="{attribute_value}" />
                <xsl:if test="current-group()[2]">
                    <element name="{@attribute_name}s" value="{string-join(current-group()/attribute_value, ',')}" />
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works great! Your answer is short and simple. Just a note, I used "{attribute_name}s" instead of "{@attribute_name}s" inside the test condition to pluralise the attribute name.

Comment: Yes, `attribute_name` is correct. The use of `@` was a typo in my answer.