# XSLT Getting values based on other elements' values

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML:

```
   <data>
      <name>att1</name>
      <value>BLUE</value>
   </data>  
   <data>
      <name>id</name>
      <value>5864828</value>
    </data>
    <data>
      <name>att2</name>
      <value>XL</value>
    </data>
    <data>
      <name>status</name>
      <value>In-Stock</value>
    </data>
```

and I need to transform it to:

```
<product>
  <id>5864828</id>
  <color>BLUE</color>
  <size>XL</size>
  <avail>In-Stock</avail>
</product>
```

I have found the following question:
[Concatenate XSLT element values based on another element value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502030/concatenate-xslt-element-values-based-on-another-element-value)
but in that thread, the solution provided is using "xsl-if" when changing the name of the attribute and it doesn't care about changing the order in which the data should be displayed.

So my questions here, is there a way in which I don't have to use xsl-if and can actually change the order of the attributes?

Comment: "is there a way in which I don't have to use xsl-if and can actually change the order of the attributes?". That is confusing. Neither your input XML nor the desired output contains any attributes. And the input does not have a root element.

Comment: @mzjn Sorry for the confusion, attributes refer to product attributes (color, size, etc..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired output can be achieved by combining selecting matching templates in the order and (instead if `xsl-if`) `xsl-choose` to create the elements.

I invented an arbitrary `<root>` element to compensate the missing one in your sample xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- always start out matching the document root -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- match the root element (not shown in your example) -->
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:element name="product">
            <!-- apply templates in the desired order, specifically selecting matching 'data' elements -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="data[name/text() = 'id']" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="data[name/text() = 'att1']" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="data[name/text() = 'att2']" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="data[name/text() = 'status']" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="data">
        <!-- choose the desired output element based on the current data/name text -->
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="./name[text() = 'id']">
                <xsl:element name="id">
                    <xsl:value-of select="./value" />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="./name[text() = 'att1']">
                <xsl:element name="color">
                    <xsl:value-of select="./value" />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="./name[text() = 'att2']">
                <xsl:element name="size">
                    <xsl:value-of select="./value" />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="./name[text() = 'status']">
            <xsl:element name="avail">
                    <xsl:value-of select="./value" />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise />
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Most common misconception about xslt is to try `xsl-foreach` - using matching templates is the way to go but it can be hard to express the needed xpath to get the desired conditions.